# RealmSwift List not saving after application close and re-open

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have two RealmSwift objects:

```
final class ListDB: Object {
    dynamic var name:String?
    dynamic var server_id:String?

    let friends = List<Friend>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "server_id"
    }
}
```

And

```
final class Friend: Object {
    dynamic var id:String?
    dynamic var name:String?

    let lists = LinkingObjects(fromType:ListDB.self, property: "friends")

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

I try appending Friend to ListDB as the following:

```
let list = self.realm.object(ofType: ListDB.self, forPrimaryKey: "SomeListID")
let friend = self.realm.object(ofType: Friend.self, forPrimaryKey: "SomeFriendID")
if friend != nil && list != nil {
      try! self.realm.write {
            list?.friends.append(friend!)
      }
}
```

And it works fine if I try to

```
print(list?.friends)
```

It works fine while I'm still in same session but if I close the app and re-open it, the friends in the specified list are gone like they were never added, what am I doing wrong?

I'm using RealmSwift latest version, iOS 10.0 as deployment target.

I also tried to update the list after I've added friends, but it won't work neither.

```
try! self.realm.write {
    self.realm.add(list!, update: true)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find your solution? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I had a function that removes all the friends and re-add them, so realm automatically deleted the friends from the list, that was my issue.